# PDO Query check if value exists

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using excelreader and I wan't a query to the databse to check if the names in the xls file exists if so it will throw a query:

name1 - exists
name2 - doesn't exist

I tried a few things but this is what I have right now:

```
<?php

require_once '../php/excelreader/reader.php';
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$data->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');


$file = $_FILES['xls'];

$data->read($file['tmp_name']);

$results = '';

var_dump($data);

$sql_details = array(
    'user' => 'root',
    'pass' => 'root',
    'db'   => 'database',
    'host' => 'localhost'
);


    $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$sql_details['host'].';dbname='.$sql_details['db'], $sql_details['user'], $sql_details['pass']);
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT name FROM users WHERE name = ?");
    $stmt->bindParam(5, $value);
    $stmt->execute();

foreach($data->sheets[0]['cells'] as $value){
    $curBrand = $value[1];

    if( $stmt->rowCount() > 0 ) { # If rows are found for query
     echo "$value[1] found!";
    }
    else {
         echo "$value[1] not found! <br/>";
    }

}



?>
```

this doesn't work I don't know how to do it since I'm pretty much new to it.

The code above just echos:

test not found! 
test2 not found! 
ttest4 not found! 
gasdgf not found!

also it throws a error: `Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in /home/server/data/compare.php on line 27`

Comment: Start by visiting this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html then compare it with what you're using in your query. Also visit http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and get the real reason/error, and possibly http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Please take a look at your code, Its a complete nonsence.

Answer (score 2):

[`bindParam()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) requires the 1-indexed position of the parameter. You're using

```
$stmt->bindParam(5, $value);
```

The `5` should be a `1`. Additionally, And as many others have pointed out, `$value` here is not set. You don't set it until *after* you try to run the query.

You should also use backticks in your query if you insist on using key/reserved words like 'name':

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `name` FROM `users` WHERE `name` = ?");
```

Add `$<your_connection>->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);` right after the connection is opened to catch PDO errors. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`
to catch other errors.

Comment: Oh if only that was all that was wrong with that code. You, thats the OP and not Jay, dont give an actual value to `$value` until after the query has been executed. So the query will not do as expected anyway.

Comment: Errors are gone thanks alot! @RiggsFolly What do I need to do now? I don't know what to do im stuck pretty much

Comment: I have no idea from your code what you are actually trying to do. Maybe you should employ a developer.

Answer (score 1):

You have only one param so in:

```
  $stmt->bindParam(5, $value);
```

you are telling 'query' you have 5 params. 
 Correct to 1

```
 $stmt->bindParam(1, $value);
```